# How to model many-to-many relationship in Android Room with CrossRef Junction

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

How would I model a many-to-many relationship as described in https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#many-to-many, but with an additional property on the junction? I basically want to achieve the following:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Playlist(
    @PrimaryKey val playlistId: Long,
    val playlistName: String
)

@Entity
data class Song(
    @PrimaryKey val songId: Long,
    val songName: String,
    val artist: String
)

@Entity(primaryKeys = ["playlistId", "songId"])
data class PlaylistSongCrossRef(
    val playlistId: Long,
    val songId: Long,
    val rating: Int // <-- the additional property
)

data class PlaylistWithRating(
    val playlist: Playlist,
    val rating: Int // <-- the additional property
)

data class SongWithPlaylists(
    @Embedded val song: Song,
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "songId",
         entityColumn = "playlistId",
         associateBy = @Junction(PlaylistSongCrossRef::class)
    )
    val playlists: List<PlaylistWithRating>
)
```

so I could access it in my Dao:

```
@Dao
interface SongWithPlaylistsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Song")
    fun list(): LiveData<List<SongWithPlaylists>>
}
```

I know how, from an ERM perspective, you would model this relationship like this:

```
/-- A ---\      /- ACrossB -\            /-- B ---\
|        |      |           |            |        |
| - id   |----->|  - aId    |     |------| - id   |
| - name |      |  - bId    |-----|      |  -name |
|        |      |  - prop   |            |        |
\--------/      \-----------/            \--------/
```

I also know how to query this relationship using `JOIN`, but couldn't figure out from the docs how to do this in Room while keeping data integrity.

Comment: I want to know about your additional property `rating` is for what? For playlist or for song?

Comment: The rating is for the combination of song and playlist. A song can have different ratings on different playlists.

Comment: have you solved this? I have a similar issue (I need the additional property for ordering of the songs in the playlist)

Comment: No, sorry. I did not have the time to keep looking into Android Room.

Comment: @Jeremy My English is poor but I opened an issue in google issue tracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169467510
I ran into the same problem and the only workaround I think is to use dirty Sqlite

Comment: Had the same problem and this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908947/android-room-fetch-data-with-where-cross-reference-data-class-has-a-third-party) helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and finally achieved it in other way. There are cases when you can not assign an attribute to any side of the binary relationship so the attribute belongs to the relationship itself.

### Step 1 -> define entity A and entity B

```
@Entity
data class Playlist(
    @PrimaryKey val playlistId: Long,
    val playlistName: String
)

@Entity
data class Song(
    @PrimaryKey val songId: Long,
    val songName: String,
    val artist: String
)
```

### Step2 -> define the associative entity(CrossRef entity), and add your additional attribute to it

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["playlistId", "songId"])
data class PlaylistSongCrossRef(
    val playlistId: Long,
    val songId: Long,
    val rating: Int // <-- the additional property
)
```

till now it was all repeating your code :D

### Step3 -> define the desired data model (Pojo) suitable to your query needs

Lets consider you want to use `SongWithPlaylists` model class. In `SongWithPlaylists` you should omit `@Relation` annotation from `playlists` and instead annotate it with @Embedded.

**Note->** change `playlists` type from `List<PlaylistWithRating>` to `Playlist`. No need to use `PlaylistWithRating`, just Playlist not even a list of it. Room no longer manages join for us. we will make it :D
And also add your CrossRef's additional attributes to `SongWithPlaylists` cause we want that additional attribute to be mapped to this object after join query finished.
`SongWithPlayList` will be like bellow

```
data class SongWithPlaylists(
    @Embedded val song: Song,
    @Embedded val playlist: Playlist,
    val rating: Int
)
```

### Step4 -> Add plain `Join` query to your `DAO`

now that you get rid of `@Relation` annotation and `PlaylistWithRatings`, you should inner join your entity A on Entity B and again join on CrossRef entity.

DAO is like bellow

```
@Dao
interface SongWithPlaylistsDao {
    @Query("""
        select Song.songId,Song.songName,Song.artist,Playlist.playlistId,Playlist.playlistName,PlaylistSongCrossRef.rating
        from Song inner join PlaylistSongCrossRef on Song.songId = PlaylistSongCrossRef.songId 
        inner join Playlist on Playlist.playlistId = PlaylistSongCrossRef.playlistId
        """)
    fun list(): LiveData<List<SongWithPlaylists>>
}
```

This was the dirty way but worked for me. Sorry for my poor English. I Hope helped you and anybody may would run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this :

@Entity
data class PlaylistSongCrossRef(
    val playlistId: Long,
    val songId: Long,

```
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val rating: Int // <-- the additional property
```

)

Note : not sure for the way to declare the primary in kotlin, I m java developper.
But you've got the idea..
The junction will still works, while you can have many association with the same song differentiated by a unique rating.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to treat the `PlaylistSongCrossRef` as an entity of its own.

Instead of defining one many-to-many relationship, you define two relationships:

1. A one-to-many relationship between `Playlist` and `PlaylistSongCrossRef`, and
2. a many-to-one relationship between `PlaylistSongCrossRef` and `Song`.

I would recommend to rename `PlaylistSongCrossRef` to something like `PlaylistSongParameters` to avoid clashing with the naming convention of many-to-many relationships.

You can even query all three entities in one go without writing custom queries. The Room documentation describes this in the ["nested relationships"](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-relationships) section.

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to create a new data class `PlaylistWithRating`. Because you can set the additional property `rating` to entity directly. For example,

If your `rating` is for `playlist`, you can set this property as follow.

```
@Entity
data class Playlist(
    @PrimaryKey val playlistId: Long,
    val userCreatorId: Long,
    val playlistName: String,
    val rating: Int // <-- the additional property
)
```

If your `rating` is for `song`, you can set this property as follow.

```
@Entity
data class Song(
    @PrimaryKey val songId: Long,
    val songName: String,
    val artist: String,
    val rating: Int // <-- the additional property
)
```

So, the `many-to-many` relation of your schema as you mentioned document will be correct. You don't need to consider additional data class for `rating` property.

So, it might be as follow.

```
@Entity
data class Playlist(
    @PrimaryKey val playlistId: Long,
    val userCreatorId: Long,
    val playlistName: String,
    val rating: Int // <-- the additional property
)

@Entity
data class Song(
    @PrimaryKey val songId: Long,
    val songName: String,
    val artist: String
)

@Entity(primaryKeys = ["playlistId", "songId"])
data class PlaylistSongCrossRef(
    val playlistId: Long,
    val songId: Long
)

data class PlaylistWithSongs(
    @Embedded val playlist: Playlist,
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "playlistId",
         entityColumn = "songId",
         associateBy = @Junction(PlaylistSongCrossRef::class)
    )
    val songs: List<Song>
)

data class SongWithPlaylists(
    @Embedded val song: Song,
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "songId",
         entityColumn = "playlistId",
         associateBy = @Junction(PlaylistSongCrossRef::class)
    )
    val playlists: List<Playlist>
)
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: tnx for your effort. but let's assume we can not assign that additional attribute (rating in this case) to any of the entites. I ran into a similar problem which additional attribute is purely for associative entity.